# .NET Microsoft Reporting always formats numbers with commas in Windows 8.1

Tags: .net, internationalization, windows-8.1, microsoft-reporting

I have developed an application with .NET that uses Microsoft Reporting. It is running for 5 years withouth any problems on Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8. Since Microsoft has released Windows 8.1 the problem is that all numbers in my reports will be formated  with commas instead of the users current region settings.

I tried many things to solve the problem:

- explicit set the Language-Property to "de-CH" in the rdlc-Report template --> this culture uses "." to format numbers
- using "String.Format(IFormatProvider, Value) in the table cells in the rdlc-Report template --> provide a "de-CH" format provider
- tried different versions of assemblies for the ReportViewer 10.0 (Visual Studio 2010) and 11.0 (Visual Studio 2012)
- set the format in the windows 8.1 system settings to "Deutsch (Schweiz)" which corresponds to "de-CH"

Has anybody the same problems? Is there a setting in Windows 8.1 that overrides my decimal separator? 
As mentioned already above: Under Window 8.0 it runs withouth any Problems!

Comment: Inspecting the CultureInfo for de-CH, I see a `CurrencyDecimalSeparator` of `.` and a `NumberDecimalSeparator` of ` ` (space). There are also different GroupSeparators. Maybe you need to format it as "Currency" instead of "Number"?

Answer (score 1):

Thats the solution: Use Locale Builder 2.0 from Microsoft to override the current "de-CH" settings.

[Locale Builder 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41158)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a known issue in Windows 8.1: the de-CH locale's `NumberDecimalSeparator` is wrong.

To avoid having to send a custom de-CH from Microsoft's Locale Builder to all my customers, I work around it by setting the `NumberDecimalSeparator` explicitly:

```
if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "de-CH")
{
    // fix Windows 8.1 de-CH locale 
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
}
```

Not terribly elegant, but works.